# SQL to match to tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two results of query one is:

```
amount | percent
100    | 10
200    | 20
300    | 30
400    | 40
```

and second is:

```
sales
10
20
110
120
210
220
310
320
```

is there way to get smthing like this:

```
sales                      | percent
30 (this is sum below 100) | 10
230(this is sum between 100 and 200) | 20
430(this is sum between 200 and 300) | 30
630(this is sum between 300 and 400) | 40
```

i thought to do it with PHP arrays and loops but I prefer not sending many requests to server. any suggestions?

Comment: Making with arrays and loops is actually AVOIDING extra requests.

Comment: Bonatoc i was going to send as many requests as many percent data there were, with where clos,  so it would increase it

Comment: Can you make tables structure clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subquery will execute query many times and it's no good
it will be better to do that with php
like this (instead of queries i have $first and $second array)

```
$first = array(
    array(
        'amount' => 100,
        'percent' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 200,
        'percent' => 20
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 300,
        'percent' => 30
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 400,
        'percent' => 40
    )
);
$second = array(
    array(
        'sales' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'sales' => 20
    ),
    array(
        'sales' => 110
    ),
    array(
        'sales' => 120
    ),
    array(
        'sales' => 210
    ),
    array(
        'sales' => 220
    ),
    array(
        'sales' => 310
    ),
    array(
        'sales' => 320
    )
);

$result = array();
$second_len = count($second);
$s=0;
for ($i=0,$len=count($first); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $sum = 0;
    for (;$s < $second_len; $s++) {
        if ($second[$s]['sales'] <= $first[$i]['amount']) {
            $sum += $second[$s]['sales'];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $result[] = array(
        'sales' => $sum,
        'percent' => $first[$i]['percent']
    );
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, lookup the correct percent for each row in the second result set, using a correlated subquery.  Then aggregate by that:

```
select percent, sum(sales)
from (select q2.*,
             (select q1.percent
              from query1 q1
              where q1.amount >= q2.sales
              order by q1.amount desc
              limit 1
             ) as percent
      from query2 q2
     ) q
group by percent;
```

Comment: it gives an error: unknown column 'q.amount' in where clause

Comment: @funny . . . That should have been `q2.sales`.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have two "results of query". I guess they come from tables. So, assuming you have the following two tables:

```
thresholds
----------
amount | percent
100    | 10
200    | 20
300    | 30
400    | 40

sales
-----
amount
10
20
110
120
210
220
310
320
```

you could get your results with this query:

```sql
SELECT
   SUM(sales_amount) sales
  ,threshold_percent percent
FROM (
  SELECT 
     s.amount sales_amount
    ,t.amount threshold_amount 
    ,t.percent threshold_percent
  FROM sales s
  INNER JOIN thresholds t
    ON t.amount > s.amount
  LEFT JOIN thresholds t2
    ON t2.amount < t.amount
    AND t2.amount > s.amount
  WHERE t2.amount IS NULL
) sales_percents
GROUP BY threshold_amount
```

You can check the query here: [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb044/4)

This should run reasonably fast as long as you have indexes on `thresholds.amount` and `sales.amount`.

Comment: @funny Then you can either (1) substitute the suggested query by replacing the tables with the appropriate subqueries or (2) work with temporary tables. Admittedly, if the queries involved are costly or complex it may be better to do the computation in application code as others have suggested.